# jquery add wrapper divs around 2 divs where content can be varient length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<div class="pagenavcounter">Page 2 of 4</div><p>
<strong>test test</strong></p>
</div>
<ul class="ticklist">
<li>Test Content</li>
<li>
     Test Content</li>
<li>
    Test Content </li>
<li>
     Test Content*</li>
</ul>
<p>
<strong>Package Extras</strong></p>
<ul>
<li>
    Test Contentt<sup>#</sup></li>
<li>
    Test Content</li>
<li>
    Test Content</li>
</ul>
<table class="stripeTable" style="width:95%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="518">
<tbody>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="customerDetailsThead header" colspan="2">
            <p>
                <strong>Key features</strong></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td class="customerDetails" style="width:35.0%;">
            <p>
                test</p>
        </td>
        <td class="customerDetails">
            <p>
                test</p>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<p>
<sup>contwent contese</sup>
</p>
<div class="pagenavbar"><div>
```

I need to insert with jQuery a wrapper div that starts after pagenavcounter and ends before pagenavbar?

The content between the two can be varying amounts..

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you propose any tried solutions?

Comment: You have two closing divs after you first opening div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do the job, assuming the two divs you mention are siblings. (If they are not siblings it doesn't really make sense to wrap everything between them in a single element.)

```
$("div.pagenavcounter").nextUntil("div.pagenavbar")
                       .wrapAll( $("<div></div>").addClass("wrapper") );
```

Where the element that you pass to the `.wrapAll()` method will be the new wrapper - for demonstration purposes I'm simply creating a new empty div and giving it the class `"wrapper"`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/SpPzh/

If `.nextUntil()` and `.wrapAll()` are not self-explanatory you know [where to look](http://api.jquery.com/)...